Creating a tuple type from a union of string literals in TypeScript
I'm trying to create a n-tuple type in TypeScript from a union of string literals, where each tuple contains exactly one string literal from the union. For example, given the union type:
type Keys = "a" | "b" | "c";

I want to create a tuple type that is exactly ["a", "b", "c"] instead of ("a" | "b" | "c")[]
How can this be achieved?
